# How to link storyboard to view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard

I am trying to connect a storyboard which I made to my view controller file in my chat app.

What I did is...

1) Create a view controller file(swift).

2) Create a storyboard file and set view controller class as a custom class.

3) Connect my component(table view) in my storyboard to a view controller as an outlet.

Now, I got "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" error message.

Code is the following.

```
import UIKit

class ChatViewController: UIViewController {

    var _device_width: Int = 0
    var _device_height: Int = 0
    var _footer_size: Int = 0
    var _backBtn: UIBarButtonItem!
    var window: UIWindow?
    var _toolBar: UIToolbar!
    var bottomView: ChatRoomInputView!
    var chats: [ChatEntity] = []

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        showNavigateBar()

        setupUI()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
        return bottomView
    }


    func showNavigateBar() {
        let backButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
        navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButtonItem
        self.title = 'My App'

    }
}

extension ChatViewController {
    func setupUI() {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 113/255, green: 148/255, blue: 194/255, alpha: 1)

        // ERROR happen on this line.
        // "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"
        tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clear


        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 10000
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.allowsSelection = false
        tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive

        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "YourChatViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "YourChat")
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "MyChatViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyChat")

        let chat1 = ChatEntity(text: "text1", time: "10:01", userType: .I)
        let chat2 = ChatEntity(text: "text2", time: "10:02", userType: .You)
        let chat3 = ChatEntity(text: "text3", time: "10:03", userType: .I)
        chats = [chat1, chat2, chat3]
    }
}

extension ChatViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.chats.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let chat = self.chats[indexPath.row]
        if chat.isMyChat() {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyChat") as! MyChatViewCell
            cell.clipsToBounds = true
            // Todo: isRead
            cell.updateCell(text: chat.text, time: chat.time, isRead: true)
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "YourChat") as! YourChatViewCell
            cell.clipsToBounds = true
            cell.updateCell(text: chat.text, time: chat.time)
            return cell
        }
    }
}

extension ChatViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(indexPath)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 10
    }
}
```

And I defined view controller as a custom class.
[image]

What should I do to work correct?
Please give me an advice.

ADD)

ChatViewController is called by another class file.

```
let chatViewController = ChatViewController()
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(chatViewController, animated: false)
```

And I believe @IBOutlet is connect correctly.

ChatViewController.swift

[image]

ChatViewController.storyboard

[image]

And I know the tableView is nil when this function was called.

[image]
Actually, I don't know much about the storyboard because I usually don't use storyboard. I prefer to create UI by the code. But now, I have to use storyboard file because I want to use a sample project of the chat system.

ADD2)

I think I may mistake the setting of the storyboard. I have no idea how to use navigation controller or entry point on the storyboard.

[image]

Comment: Which line gives the exception?

Comment: Also, if you are using a storyboard, don't register nib files; use prototype cells in your storyboard scene.

Comment: try to debug and trace which line gives you error of force fully wrapping a nil value.

Comment: The error is happen the following code. "tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clear"

Comment: check tableView `@IBOutlet` make sure it's connected correctly in your Interface builder Element

Comment: How/where is initalized `ChatViewController`? You launch the Storyboard?

Comment: Do you confirm your tableview.delegate and tableview.datasource in this class? and also check that you set cell reusable identifier properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem.

I modified call method.

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "ChatViewController", bundle:nil)
let chatViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChatViewController") 
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(chatViewController, animated: true)
```

Thank you for your kindness advice.

Answer (score 0):

You should add delegate and datasource in your viewLoad() function.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    showNavigateBar()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    setupUI()
}
```

If error still exist after that, check your "Outlets" in your Storyboard.

Comment: I add delegate and datasource code. But I got nil found error when "tableView.delegate = self" attempt to run.